# Disable resizing of specific elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Using the latest twitter bootstrap package I have a problem with an column being resized and it does destroy the design of items inside that column.

Two questions:

1. Is there a easy way of blocking an element (column/div) to be resized.
2. Even with quite a lot of empty space to the right the "resize" gets trigged too early what I can see, anyway to control this?

**Update:**
As the site is made with Python Flask and Jinja2 templates its a bit messy to get all the code but I got an test page showing the problem
http://www.biddingpractice.com/test/test

Comment: `spanX` does not get resized in normal conditions. Can you share your code to know what's happening?

Comment: @simbirsk sounds like bootstrap-responsive is used. I agree on the fact some code would helps.

Comment: Updated my post with a link to the page with the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nesting two `.container` consecutively and you have no `.row`. To keep your layout working you have to wrap avery `.spanX` in a `.row`, and never nest consecutively two equal elements (containers, rows or spans). Remember also that in a `.row`, spans must add up 12.

Your markup should be:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6"></div>
        <div class="span6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My Jinja templates had a few extra divs etc and did not realise this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. or fix the size of your column in px instead of the (row > spanx)
2. the resizing come from the media queries in bootstrap-responsive.css http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive

It may be better not to use bootstrap-responsive.css, but some code/example will helps to confirm.